# Ejecución de un .jar mediante Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, jvm

Colegas necesito ayuda con una sentencia en Java. Tengo una aplicación en un .jar que mando a ejecutar con la sentencia:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(java -jar "/direccion/app.jar");
```

Lo que ocurre es que la aplicación que se está ejecutando dentro del .jar no se termina de ejecutar por completo. Me explico: si la aplicación necesita analizar 20 objetos solo analiza 10 de ellos. No sé qué puede suceder pues el código que está dentro del .jar funciona perfectamente de manera independiente, es decir, como clases java analizan lo 20 objetos que debe analizar. Necesito usar la aplicación como .jar y no entiendo qué puede estar pasando. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que usas es correcto.

Tienes que comprobar que el .jar funcione. Que el programa funcione correctamente en las clases, no implica que después de compilar y empaquetar sea así.

Prueba a ejecutar el .jar a través de la línea de consola (o terminal si estás en Linux) a mano. Probablemente tengas el mismo problema.

Si no funciona, prueba a usar esto:

```
// Run a java app in a separate system process
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar /direccion/app.jar");
```

Sería también muy interesante que ojeaséis esta respuesta de la web inglesa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700879/how-to-run-a-java-executable-jar-in-another-java-program

Comment: De tener el mismo problema cual sería la solución? he cosultado algunos foros y he leído comentarios acerca del tamaño del buffer y que puede que la aplicación se detenga a causa de esto, que me puede comentar acerca de esto?

Comment: Colega acabo de ejecutar el .jar directamente desde la consola y funciona perfectamente. Lo que cuando lo integro a la aplicación en la cual debo mandarlo a ejecutar no analiza todo lo que tiene que analizar? existen posibles soluciones? gracias

Comment: He editado la respuesta :)

Comment: amigo he intentado con las dos opciones pero aun no funciona con la solucion que se encuentra en el link no reporta ningun error de compilacion pero no extrae analiza ni siquiera un objeto? alguna otra variante? gracias de antemano